# Is Firebase Remote Config does a delta sync or does it downloads all the configs every time?

Tags: android, firebase, data-synchronization, firebase-remote-config

I'm evaluating Firebase  Remote Config for it's data consumption and immediate reacting ability,I'm left with following questions.

1. When some one changes config from the console does my users end up downloading all the data or only the changed delta?
2. Does Fire base do a immediate sync when the value in the console changes or only at the cache timeout?
3. Is there a way to force the config update from console?

Background: My app users have very scarce access to network data and we already have rest API for app configs!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If a change has been made in Remote Config then all parameter will be retrieved by the client. If no changes are made then a request will not download any of the parameters. Note that initial parameters should be added locally on the device, and only when a change is necessary you should add the changed value to the console.
2. When the client retrieves values from the server is up to you. When you call fetch you can specify how old of a cache you are willing to accept. So if you always want to retrieve parameters from the server you can call fetch(0) indicating that no cached parameter is fresh enough, but note that there is an hourly limit to how often you can fetch parameters from the server.
3. No, the client is responsible for fetching parameters from the server.

For more on Firebase Remote Config caching see the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android#caching).